# Передача параметра родительского джоба в jenkins pipeline дочерний вызываемый через build job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins pipeline содержит древовидную иерархию вызовов дочерних джобов через build job в зависимости от условий.

```
Job A
Job B
Job C

A -> B -> C
A -> C
B -> C
```

Итд, и нужно, что бы понимать что послужило причиной запуска того или иного джоба. Для отслеживания первоисточника запуска.

Задача такова, что бы идентификатор пайплайна, который был самым верхним сохранять в виде переменной во всех дочерних джобах, при этом дочерние джобы могут вызываться и самостоятельно, нужно что бы в этом случае пайплайн не падал с ошибкой, а правильно распознавал переменные.
Смотрел в сторону плагина `[promoted builds][1]` но не нашел нигде примеров использования в пайплайне. Есть какие то идеи или примеры использования плагина promoted builds?

Передавать через params не очень хочется, так как древовидность достаточно сложная, велика вероятность того, что где то сработает человеческий фактор.